# Google Play Game Services - testing leaderboards/achievements

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am about to integrate my Android game with GP Game Services, and was wondering if there are any tools for separating data generated during testing from actual players' data. For example, I do not want my achievements/leaderboard scores that belong to my testing accounts to show up at all in production. 
What is the usual approach here, what kind of tools do I have? I did not anything useful so far, which suggests I have to live with the problem. Alternatively I could create another game (for testing) on the Play console, use that for testing, while the production APK would use the 'normal' game... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Play Games Services Managment Tools](https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools) to do that.

The following is possible using this tool (as specified on the linked site):

- Reset, show, hide, and unlock Achievements
- Perform administration on Leaderboards such as hiding players
- Test and administrate Events and Quests
- Inspect Snapshot data

Comment: Though I abandoned GPS Games API because of its stability and API usability problems, the solution in the above answer worked.

Comment: I too find it a bit annoying to work with, but at least it's something.